# How can I make a RadioButtonBar that randomizes the choices each time a notebook is opened?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, notebooks

I have the following function for making a `RadioButtonBar` with randomized choices. The code is

```
makeQuestionRandom[title1_, choices1_, appearance1_, question1__] :=

 DynamicModule[{title = title1, choices = choices1, 
   appearance = appearance1, question = question1, selection = 0},
  Panel[
   Grid[{
     {question},
     {RadioButtonBar[ Dynamic[selection], RandomSample[choices], 
       Appearance -> "Vertical" -> appearance,
       ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {25, 0}}
       ](*close radiobutton bar*)
      }(*close radiobutton bar entry for grid*),
     {Dynamic[
       Switch[selection, 1, Style["Correct!", Darker[Green, .25]], 0, 
        " ", _, Style["Wrong ", Darker[Red]]]]
      }(*close dynamic text row*)
     },(*close grid matrix*)

    Alignment -> Left,
         Spacings -> {{2, 2}, {2, 2}}
    ],(*close grid bracket*)
   title
   ](*close panel bracket*)
  ](*close dynamicmodule bracket*)
```

The output looks like

[image]

What I would like is for this output to 'execute' each time the notebook is opened.  I'm trying to create notebooks that are quizzes and the questions will look like this.  Hence my desire for having the choices randomized each time the notebook is opened without showing the code that generated the output.

Comment: Could you mark all of the question cells as initialisation cells [Cells | Cell Properties | Initialization Cell] and and convert to a CDF. When the CDF is opened I believe it will run all of the initialisation cells.  Test it for a couple of questions and see if it works.

Comment: I was not able to make this work.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I hadn't considered anything along these lines and didn't know about initialization cell properties.

Comment: DynamicModule has an option Initialization, of which the contents is executed each time when the DynamicModule is first displayed, so in particular when the notebook is opened. Would that be helpful for you?

Comment: Yes, that works.  Edmund was on the right track.  I just didn't try initialization with DynamicModule.  When I read the documentation I thought "first displayed" literally meant when it was first displayed throughout all history.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fred has suggested, `Initialization` is the way to go, and here is a minimal example:

```
DynamicModule[{answer, answers = Range@10, order},
  Column[{
    "Pick 1:",
    Dynamic[RadioButtonBar[Dynamic@answer, answers[[order]]], 
      TrackedSymbols :> {order}]
  }]
  ,
  Initialization :> ( order = RandomSample@Range@Length@answers; ),
  UnsavedVariables :> {answer}

]
```

> [image]